# Determining how many terminals are open

Tags: terminal, gnome

I have been struggling with this for about 8 hours now. I need to write a piece of C code to determine how many terminals are currently open. The user has opened these terminals before the code is ever run. I know that it would be much easier to just have the code create the gnome terminals during run time, however, this is not an open. I need to do this by looping through all possible terminal buffer files, determine which ones are currently is use and assign file descriptors to those that are already open. This is what I have so far.

```
for(i=0; i<26; i++)
{
    sprintf(termPath, "/dev/pts/%d", i); 
    term = open(termPath, O_RDWR);
    fprintf(term, "Term %d: %d\n", i, term);
}
```

What is wrong here? I currently have /dev/pts/0, /dev/pts/11, and /dev/pts/17 open as gnome terminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be simpler and more effective (as well as more portable) to open a pipe to the [`w`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?w) or [`who`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?who) commands and count the number of entries which correspond to your user.  Most terminal emulators (even gnome-terminal) update the `utmp` information which these commands use.

Here is a listing to show the type of output from `w`:

```
~ (101) w
 05:08:14 up  1:04,  5 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
tom      pts/1    thathost:S.0     04:44   43.00s  0.61s  0.50s ssh -X michener
tom      pts/2    thathost:S.1     04:45   22:21   0.11s  0.11s -bin/tcsh
tom      pts/3    thathost:S.3     05:05    1:08   0.11s  0.07s ded /usr/build/
tom      pts/4    thathost:S.2     04:46   21:09   0.90s  0.87s vile
tom      pts/5    thathost:S.4     05:08    0.00s  0.03s  0.00s w
```

The manual page for [`w`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?w) documents the header and columns; your application could skip the header of `w`'s output, and check the first column for the given username, while extracting the second column (for the `TTY` information).

Opening each pty device to check if some other process has opened it has at least two problems:

- you have to know the names (yes, this is system-dependent)
- it depends upon the coincidence that you can usually open the same device twice - and that you are unlikely to open another user's devices

You can read the output of simple programs such as `w` using a `FILE` stream opened via [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), e.g.,

```
FILE *fp = popen("w", "r");
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) {
    ...process input
}
pclose(fp);
```

Comment: OK, so I would need to use system("who"). What then? I would need to grab the terminal buffer numbers from this somehow.